# Open/Save as... dialog box not showing

Tags: java, servlets, download, http-headers, response

I have a PDF file on my server that I need the user to download from the client side.

Using Spring Framework, I use javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse to create the correct response and corresponding header:

```
response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="content.pdf");
response.setContentLength(content.size());
```

Then I use the ServletOutputStream to write the content:

```
ServletOutputStream os;
try {
    os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(((ByteArrayOutputStream)baos).toByteArray());
    baos.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the client side, I receive HTTP code 200 and receive the correct response body, with the PDF file, but the 'Save As...' pop-up did not appear.

Is there any reason on the Header configuration that could lead to this problem or could it be somewhere else?

Thank you.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti IE 9

Comment: are you calling this code from a servlet or from a jsp page? are you sure that no other header has been set?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti I'm calling this code from a servlet. Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Check your browser settings or try other browser. May be you have set the IE to do some special behavior with PDF files (For example, save them automatically)

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

`attachment;`**space**`filename=content.pdf`

**update**

```
public static void download(HttpServletResponse response, File file, String downloadName) throws IOException
{
    if(file == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("file is null");

    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadName + "\"");

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

    try
    {
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

        try
        {
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            output.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

and the only difference i see is in the headers section.
have you tried without cache-control, pragma and expires?

**update**

no difference at all using a file or a stream:

```
public static void download(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream input, String downloadName, String contenType) throws IOException
{
    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(input.available()));
    response.setContentType(contenType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadName + "\"");

    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The file that I want to export is created with the HTTP response and are not stored in the server.

Comment: I've tried the IOUtils copy solution and didn't worked.

Beside, if we use a Network Monitor we can get the PDF file from the HTTP Response. Is it possible that I'm not closing the stream correctly?

Comment: i think the problem is not in the content but in the headers. maybe some proxy? have you tried using chrome and see the network activity for this request?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content type to `application/octet-stream` instead:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

This should force the browser to show the "Save As..." popup. If you set it to `application/pdf` the browser recognizes the file type and displays it instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this code the problem came in

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="content.pdf");
```

for defining filename

Try:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+"content.pdf");
```

It will open up dialog box and will give you save as option when clicking save button